# Rails foreign-key setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app with Client and Contact models.

```
Client has_many :contacts
Contact belongs_to :client
```

I would like to identify one of the client's contacts to be the Primary Contact. But, I'm not understanding how to do this.

Right now, I've got this in the Client model:

```
has_many :contacts
has_one :primary_contact, :class_name => "Contact", :foreign_key => "primary_contact_id"
```

And this in the Contact model:

```
belongs_to :client
belongs_to :client_as_primary, :class_name => "Client", :foreign_key => "primary_contact_id"
```

I added a field = `client.primary_contact_id`

This in a view:

```
<td> <%= @client.primary_contact.contact_full_name %></td>
```

Which gives me this:

```
SELECT  "contacts".* FROM "contacts"  WHERE "contacts"."tenant_id" = 1 AND "contacts"."primary_contact_id" = 13 LIMIT 1
```

And that gets a PG error, because `contacts.primary_contact_id` is missing

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reverse your association. Whichever class has the foreign_key should have the `belongs_to` association. In your case, `Client` model has the `foreign_key`. So `Client` should `belong_to primary_contact`

in client.rb

```
has_many :contacts
belongs_to :primary_contact, :class_name => "Contact", :foreign_key => "primary_contact_id"
```

in contact.rb

```
belongs_to :client
has_one :client_as_primary, :class_name => "Client", :foreign_key => "primary_contact_id"
```